# Grid - Width columns - Css

Tags: html, css

I have a 100% grid with 4 columns.
In some sizes I want it to be 3.
I tried to change CSS so that the width would be 25%
And a minimum of 33.33% in a certain range of screen size using CSS.
In Grid I made CSS of

```
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
```

But it is presented in such a way:

```
1   2   3 
4
5   6   7
8
```

I want a certain screen size range,
It will be responsive and will be this way:

```
100% = 1  2  3  4  
       5  6  7  8
```

in some screen size:

```
1  2  3 
4  5  6
7  8
```

I work in Elementor and the two lines are separate
If it changes anything
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use grid here and don't use `%` instead use `fr` unit.

If you need 4 columns

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); // 4 columns
```

else if you need 3 columns

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); // 3 columns
```

Just resize browser and see the difference

```css
.grid-container {
  margin: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); // 4 columns
  grid-gap: 1rem;
}

.grid-items {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); // 3 columns
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-items">1</div>
  <div class="grid-items">2</div>
  <div class="grid-items">3</div>
  <div class="grid-items">4</div>
  <div class="grid-items">5</div>
  <div class="grid-items">6</div>
  <div class="grid-items">7</div>
  <div class="grid-items">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want it to be in percent.
I have 2 sections one below the other, with the display on this computer being 4 columns.
On smaller screens (larger than a tablet) it looks not good and I want 3 columns to be displayed. The width is set to about 25% and I tried using CSS to change the size to a minimum of 33.33% in the range I want, but it hides the fourth column in each row.
I want 3 in each row to be displayed, within a certain screen size range.

display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
But it is presented in such a way:
1 2 3
4
5 6 7
8

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/t7ku9c2q/